# How do I write an "Automation" using Shortcuts to stop my workout?

Tags: apple-watch, shortcuts-app

I often forget to stop my "Workout" that is running on my watch.  I'd like an automation something like:

```
if workout is running AND
   in the area of the gym (Geofence) AND
   iPhone connects to my car (Bluetooth) THEN
  stop Workout or at least remind me to stop the Workout
```

This is partly a "is this even possible" type question because the Shortcut (I assume) will be running on my phone while the workout is running on my watch.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be to create an automation that runs when you leave the gym that sends a notification asking if your workout is still running.

If you use a specific focus while you work out, you can also get the current focus and check against that as well.

The only thing you can do regarding workouts/fitness in Shortcuts is start them; you can't end them. You also can't check for open apps. The best you can do is a notification reminder to manually end the workout.